# How do I configure Jenkins to trigger on a pull request based on the Git branch's name?

Tags: jenkins, git, automation

I want pull requests to Git where the target is master and the source has a string "foo" to trigger a Jenkins build.

If this string "foo" appears in the source branch's name when there is a pull request, I want the Jenkins build to start.

The only way I can think of doing something this sophisticated is to put the logic into a Jenkins pipeline file.  Is there a plugin or supported way of making this work?  I am not using Github.

Is there a way to filter any branch that does not have "foo" in it?  How do I trigger a build based on a pull request?  I tried doing this by itself (without the search for the pattern "foo"), and even that failed.  There were no errors, but I know Jenkins was authenticating to Git with the credentials I configured in Jenkins.  The Jenkins job would not run when the conditions I configured were met.

Comment: This depends a bit on which plugins you've got on the server - do you have access to this information?

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-branch pipeline you have several different ways of filtering branches, take for instance a regular expression for "foo". In order to use this job type, you must create a Jenkinsfile in your repo with build instructions using the scripted or declarative syntax. The term pull request is typically synonymous with services like Github and Bitbucket.

[image: multibranch pipeline branch source]

You can also filter within the pipeline itself using declarative syntax:

```
when {changeRequest branch: "foo.*", comparator: 'REGEXP' }
```

And also scripted syntax:

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /foo.*/){  
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once could use the [`when` in conjunction with the `branch` keyword if Jenkins declarative pipelines would be used](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/):

> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent any
>     stages {
>         stage('Example Build') {
>             steps {
>                 echo 'Hello World'
>             }
>         }
>         stage('Example Deploy') {
>             when {
>                 branch 'production'
>             }
>             steps {
>                 echo 'Deploying'
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```